# Change Turbogears paster serve directory

Tags: python, turbogears

I'm a bit new to Turbogears, but wondering if someone can help me out...

I have TG setup in /var/tg/user/env/
where there are dirs...

```
bin/
include/
lib/
local/
src/
paster.log
development.ini
```

I want the `paster serve development.ini` command to serve out of `src/Project/projecttg/projecttg`
But it's serving out of `lib/python2.7/site-packages/projecttg/` instead?

How do I change this?

Answer (score 0):

The projecttg was "installed" to the VM from the `lib/python2.7/site-packages/` dir.  So I had to go into `src/Project/projecttg/` and run `python setup.py develop` to overwrite it